# IBM Watson Natural Language Classifier accuracy measures

Tags: java, classification, ibm-watson

I have created an NLC service on Bluemix, I have trained it with my data, now I want to measure the Recall, Precision, and FScore.
I have written a Java file that would automate the calculation since my training data is more than 5000 lines.
I need to run the service on the server, and find a way to automate linking my script to test the Classifier. 
I am new to IBM Bluemix and have tried going through the tutorials, submitted a ticket to support seeking help and still didn't get an answer. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy the Java for Liberty runtime on Bluemix (https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/liberty-for-java?taxonomyNavigation=apps) you will get a shell sample application, that you can use as a starting shell. This app will run on Bluemix.

Then make use of the Watson Developer Cloud SDK for Java (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) for wrapper classes round the Watson service.

The API Documentation shows how to use the SDK to invoke the service (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/?java#classify).